# Show that if $gcd(a,b)|c$ then $ax+by=c$ has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Show that if $gcd(a,b)|c$ then $ax+by=c$ has infinitely many solutions.

I know that in order to find the solutions for $x$ and $y$, you can use the equations $x= x_o + (b/d)t$ and $y=y_0 - (a/d)t$ where $d=gcd(a,b)$ and $ t \in Z$. What I don't know is how to show this using some sort of proof.

Comment: Extended Euclidean algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) you can construct one solution to this equation. Call it $(x_0,y_0)$.

Then clearly, $(x_0+n \cdot b,y_0-n \cdot a)$ is a solution for any integer $n$.
This gives you an infinite number of solutions.